# Gradient of $M \mapsto \mbox{tr} \left( A^{-1} M \right) + \mbox{tr} \left( M^{-1} B \right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

Given positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, let $$f(M) := \mbox{tr} \left( A^{-1} M \right) + \mbox{tr} \left( M^{-1} B \right)$$ What is $\nabla f(N)$?

---

According to my source, $\nabla f(N)=A-N^{-1}BN^{-1}$. However, I would expect a vector. How can I compute the trace gradient and what is the shape of its value?

Comment: The space of matrices is a vector space (although of a different dimension than the vector space that the matrices act on). You differentiate a function on the vector space of matrice, so you get an element of this vector space, i.e. a matrix.

Comment: Why not provide a link to your source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ eats a matrix and spits out a number, its derivative $\nabla f(N)$ at $N$ eats a *matrix direction* and spits out a number.  How you organise that information is up to you.

For $N$ invertible and $H$ small enough, we have $N+H$ is invertible with
\begin{align*}
(N+H)^{-1}&=[N(1+N^{-1}H)]^{-1}\\
&=(I+N^{-1}H)^{-1}N^{-1}\\
&=(I-N^{-1}H+o(\lVert H\rVert))N^{-1}\\
&=N^{-1}-N^{-1}HN^{-1}+o(\lVert H\rVert)
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
f(N+H)&=\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}(N+H))+\operatorname{tr}((N+H)^{-1}B)\\
&=f(N)+\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}H)-\operatorname{tr}(N^{-1}HN^{-1}B)+o(\lVert H\rVert)\\
&=f(N)+\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}H)-\operatorname{tr}(N^{-1}BN^{-1}H)+o(\lVert H\rVert)\\
&=f(N)+\langle (A^{-1}-N^{-1}BN^{-1})^T,H\rangle_{F}+o(\lVert H\rVert)
\end{align*}
which gives
$$
\nabla f(N)(H)=\langle (A^{-1}-N^{-1}BN^{-1})^T,H\rangle_{F}
$$
where $\langle-,-\rangle_F$ is the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only you solved my problem, but you also enlightened me. I shall take back my algebra books.